# Specify on which subdomain to show node (Multisite with shared Database)

Tags: 7, multi-sites, subsites

I'm using multisite with shared database. Is there any way I can specify on which subdomain I want the content to be displayed (on node creation)?

So If I create a node, I would like to have checkboxes that say (subdomain1, subdomain2, subdomain3).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need this:

https://drupal.org/project/domain

On each node it will ask to affiliate content for specific domain and they would appear only over those for which you have selected.